# Including files using jQuery - erros with path location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, path

I have a very simple page (html) where I load a menu at the footer and content above. That content div loads an index.html inside my system located at "resources/date of the event/name of the place/index.html" using `jQuery.load()`.

Website wireframe:

[image]

Real example from the file I'm loading into div content: "resources/12-09-2016/kitchen/index.html"

Inside the html above my system has to load, mandatorily, some unique css/js/img files to make it work. That means I have to load it at the home page. My index.html that loads it is in the root folder.

The problem is when I click to load a folder inside resources I'm getting wrong path, it understands my unique CSS/Js files are inside /root/js and not /resources/12-09-2016/kitchen/js as it should.

I can't find a solution to that. Any idea to help?

Comment: What happens when you prefix your path with a dot like, `./resources/12-09-2016/kitchen/js` ?

Comment: Inside my root javascript?

Comment: In your `.load` function

Comment: Actually it does nothing, same error

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: $('.map').load( './' + value );
Where value is the location path...

Comment: I guess, you are facing this issue in your production environment (after moving all your files from local) right?

Comment: I only ran it into dev environment...

Comment: I see.. What happens when you call your `.load` function as `$('.map').load(value );` (without the trailing slash)?